# Get value from Sql Server Database and place in textBox

Tags: vb.net

i got text box but not in same form.
first textbox is staffid which in login form.
second textbox is staff first name which in sale form.

admin staffid's first name is Ng

i insert code below:

```
Private Sub txtId_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtId.TextChanged
    Sale.Staff_First_NameTextBox.Text = "select [Staff First Name] from staff where Staffid ='" & txtId.Text.Trim & "'"
End Sub
```

when i insert admin at staffid textbox ,the thing show at Staff_First_NameTextBox is

```
"select [Staff First Name] from staff where Staffid ='admin'"
```

it should be Ng...

anyone can help?

Comment: You need some basic training on database access in .net. Internet is full of stuff that can guide u in detail. Remember that a `TextBox` has nothing to do with SQL queries. It doesn't understand, nor is designed to understand what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: i use sql as my database

Comment: Are you using Access or Sql Server or what exactly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to get value from sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856686/need-to-get-value-from-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is assigning a literal `String` to the `Text` of the `TextBox`.  If that `String` actually represents a SQL query then you need to execute that query against a database and then use the result set.  You might start here to learn a bit about data access in VB.NET:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6.aspx

Comment: may show me which i should refer??

or may show some code to me ??

Comment: The idea is that data access is an entire subject that you apparently know pretty much nothing about so you need to learn the subject as a whole.  One code snippet is not going to teach you.  Do some proper research.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you could use this code to get data from your SQL Server Database

```
  Using connObj As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("<connectionString>")
     Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select firstName from staff where Staffid ='" & txtId.Text.Trim & "'", connObj)
        connObj.Open()
        Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj.ExecuteReader
           'This will loop through all returned records 
           While readerObj.Read
              Sale.Staff_First_NameTextBox.Text = readerObj("firstName").ToString
              'handle returned value before next loop here
           End While
        End Using
        connObj.Close()
     End Using
  End Using
```

Get your `<connectionString>` From App.config, know more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326022/find-the-connection-string)

Replace `firstName` in code with your column name